# how can I get post like_info through post_id?

Tags: facebook

Now I am searching for an answer,how can I get post like_info through post_id?I have asked this question because in a social exchange website I saw they asks for post id (no matter it is a photo or article).Then they detect the like_count and if anybody like that post they also detect and give points for liking the Post. I think they are not better than this site's experts. So my question is how can I get post like_info through post_id?. I have an Facebook app,app access token,and some post Id to query in fql.

Answer (score 0):

With FQL this is easy at first sight:

```
 select post_id, like_info from stream where post_id="{post_id}"
```

results in

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "post_id": "{post_id}", 
      "like_info": {
        "can_like": true, 
        "like_count": 1, 
        "user_likes": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The downsides are:

- FQL is **only available until April 30th, 2016**
- You'll need a User Access Token for the field `user_likes` to be available, not an App Access Token!

You can use the Graph API to partially achieve what you desire:

```
/{post_id}?fields=id,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)
```

This gives you the like count, but you're not able to determine of the current User likes this Post, other than parsing the array of likes and checking for the `id` of the current User afaik.

Comment: Thanks i didn't tried the fql yet.but i tried the graph api as you say.This shows me unsupported get request for this photo id-619380841477024  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=619380841477024%3Ffields%3Did%2Clikes.summary%28true%29&version=v2.0 .And i have used user_likes field also.

Comment: The id you gave is not a post_id. You were asking for Posts, not Photos!

Comment: But i have also used a post id-666336703404293 .In that website they accept it no matter it is photo post or only a post.And if i use Graph API for photo how can i do that?

Comment: Those are different object types, and thereby those types also have different fields. I gave an answer to your question, if you now change the scope the question (without even changing the question's text), I don't think that this is acceptable here at SO.

Comment: Can you please tell me why this post is returning  blank result `select post_id, like_info from stream where post_id=666336703404293` ?

Comment: 7322484249_10152386385174250 is a post_id for example

Comment: Where can i found the post_id from a post link?

Comment: For example this is the post link- [link](https://www.facebook.com/subrata.himesh/posts/666336703404293) how can i find the post_id from it?

Comment: Why would you use something from the FB website directly? There are APIs to do this programatically